# Connecting to mysql using ssh tunnel does not work

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to a remote server via ssh tunnel and then connect to a mysql.

I first tried on mysql workbench and it works fine. The "fake" information looks like this:
[image: mysql connection info]
With the same information I tried to connect to mysql with nodeJS but I have no idea how to do it. Please help. This is what I have tried so far.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');

var config = {
  username:'hoffnung8493',
  Password:'password123',
  host:'hoffnung.com',// not sure if its right
  port:22,// not sure if its right
  dstHost:'hoffnung.com',// not sure if its right
  dstPort:3306, // not sure if its right
  localHost:'127.0.0.1',// not sure if its right
  localPort: 27000 // not sure if its right
};

tunnel(config, function(error, server){
  var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',// not sure if its right
    user: 'stock_id',
    password: 'stock_password',
    database: 'database_name',
    charset  : 'utf8'
  });
db.connect();
db.query(`show tables`, function(error, result){
  console.log(error);
  console.log(1, result);
  })
})

module.exports = db; //probably wrong
```

Then from main.js I want to send query like this:

```
db = require('./lib/db.js');

db.query('show tables', function(error, result){
    console.log(result)
});
```

On my console I get the following error message:

```
0|main   | Error: All configured authentication methods failed
0|main   |     at tryNextAuth (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/tunnel-ssh/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:376:17)
0|main   |     at SSH2Stream.onUSERAUTH_FAILURE (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/tunnel-ssh/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:587:5)
0|main   |     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
0|main   |     at SSH2Stream.emit (events.js:213:7)
0|main   |     at parsePacket (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/ssh.js:3929:10)
0|main   |     at SSH2Stream._transform (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/ssh.js:669:13)
0|main   |     at SSH2Stream.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:186:10)
0|main   |     at SSH2Stream._read (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/ssh2-streams/lib/ssh.js:251:15)
0|main   |     at SSH2Stream.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:174:12)
0|main   |     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:385:12)
```

After I fixed from "Password" ->"password", I added db.query after db.connect to see if it works and I got the following error

```
0|main   | { Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'stock'@'firstpg-server197-22' (using password: YES)
0|main   |     at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
0|main   |     at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:124:18)
0|main   |     at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
0|main   |     at Parser.write (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
0|main   |     at Protocol.write (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
0|main   |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
0|main   |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
0|main   |     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
0|main   |     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
0|main   |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
0|main   |     --------------------
0|main   |     at Protocol._enqueue (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
0|main   |     at Protocol.handshake (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
0|main   |     at Connection.connect (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
0|main   |     at /home/cabox/workspace/inven_man/lib/db2.js:24:4
0|main   |     at Server.<anonymous> (/home/cabox/workspace/node_modules/tunnel-ssh/index.js:89:13)
0|main   |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
0|main   |     at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
0|main   |     at Server.emit (events.js:207:7)
0|main   |     at emitListeningNT (net.js:1349:10)
0|main   |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:11)
0|main   |   code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
0|main   |   errno: 1045,
0|main   |   sqlMessage: 'Access denied for user \'stock\'@\'firstpg-server197-22\' (using password: YES)',
0|main   |   sqlState: '28000',
0|main   |   fatal: true }
0|main   | 1 undefined
```

Comment: You you really have an uppercase `P` in `Password`? The options are case sensitive , so it should be `password`.

Comment: I'd agree with @t.niese. "Password" in `config` should instead be `password` with a lowercase "p". And another thing, username and password of what are you using?

Comment: ok i dont get the authentication error anymore. But I am getting undefined from my query results. Also am i exporting  db correctly?

Comment: Do not change your original question into a  new one by removing the original problem.  Otherwise the already given answers become wrong and useless. If you have a new question then create a new one.

Comment: If `result` is empty then most likely `error` is set. So add a check if an error occurred and inspect that error to see what the problem is. Something like `if( error ) { console.error(error) } else {  console.log(result) }` but as I said that's a new question.

Comment: i get access_denied error this time..

Comment: Do you have a mysql server running on your local machine, if so, then shut that server down, to check where the connection is going to. If you still get the same error,  then it is a new problem and **has to be asked in a new question**, because then tunneling works. But if the error changes to `ECONNREFUSED` then you haven't included the `port: 27000` in your `mysql.createConnection` options, as already described in my answer.

Comment: im using a cloud ide called codeanywhere.com. They provide me with a virtual machine and local mysql server. I dont understand what you mean by shutting the mysql server down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant test it right now, but it should be sufficient to set `port` in the options to `27000`.

```
tunnel(config, function(error, server){
  var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 27000, // the local port you defined for your tunnel
    user: 'stock_id',
    password: 'stock_password',
    database: 'database_name',
    charset  : 'utf8'
  });
  db.connect();
})
```

Beside that the options are case sensitive, so it should be `password` and not `Password`.

```
var config = {
  username:'hoffnung8493',
  password:'password123',
  host:'hoffnung.com',// not sure if its right
  port:22,// not sure if its right
  dstHost:'hoffnung.com',// not sure if its right
  dstPort:3306, // not sure if its right
  localHost:'127.0.0.1',// not sure if its right
  localPort: 27000 // not sure if its right
};
```

Comment: i added the port number but I still get error("ALL configured authentication methods failed")

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to suggest you to change / hide the domain name in the future, just for caution cases.
Secondly, can you post the output you get from the console? If you get any output.
Thirdly, as this is an ssh connection matter, you need to make sure you are set as allowed to connect to the remote server, on port 22 in this case, whether in it's settings / firewall settings.

Regarding the settings, double check the variable values to be sure not to confuse between the MySQL and SSH connections variables, rely on the fact that the MySQL Workbench connection is working.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have posted the error shown on console.

Comment: The variables on mysql workbench is the correct ones. Because I had successful connection there. But Im not sure if I did the right match on node.js Thats where I need help